# Why no trilane in pubs?

Tags: dota-2

The question is simple. I play a lot of pubgames and i have almost never seen a trilane. If you think that all pro teams form trilanes and it is the best strategy to get a lot of farm for your carry and win, why nobody tries the same in pubs?

Comment: What MMR? I see them probably every third game at ~4000. I think it's probably just that low level players don't follow competitive play. Also, see my answer [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106816/proper-trilane-setup) for details on how to actually run the trilane properly, which will help if you're new to using the strategy.

Comment: I see it very rarely, and usually only when playing against parties of 5 or a party of 3 is involved.  It's something that is easy to dismantle when 5 random people are doing it, so I'm guessing people don't even bother. I would never even consider it when I'm solo queueing, sounds like the fastest way to lose.

Comment: I see trilanes once in every 4/5 games @4500 MMR so thats like 20/25% of my games

Comment: I do it all the time at ~2500.  Granted, I'm nearly always in a stack of at least 3, but I've had many successful trilanes with randoms, too.

Comment: Huh, I don't play ranked (usually play 1-2 month in spurts, not enough to be consistent) so it's less common/non-existent in unranked I guess?

Comment: @turbo I tend to see it more in unranked than ranked, actually.  Though I seem to see a vastly more skilled "trench" than most people describe...

Comment: @JohntheGreen Hm, I think unranked might still have some sort of hidden ELO metric? I could just be a lot lower. I also tend to play SD for the most part and then AR/CD/RD when I'm playing with friends.  Perhaps it's more common in AP/CM?

Comment: @turbo I seem to recall a hidden MMR for unranked being mentioned in a blog post by Valve, which makes sense as I tend to win most of my unranked games and lose most of my ranked games :P  Also, I queue for everything *but* AP/CM/CD

Comment: @JohntheGreen Huh, then I don't really know. Maybe I should finish my qualifying ranked matches and figure out how bad I really am. edit: just found out you can check your mmr with some console commands before you get 10 games complete, I'll check later.

Comment: @turbo : this was possible but was removed from valve again. So at the moment you still need to finish 10 ranked games.

Comment: @Wangdang yeah found that out when I tried. Funny enough, I played two ranked games yesterday and had a 3 stack on my team pull off a trilane ending in a 26 min win

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that's necessary to make tri-lanes work is that the supports need to know how to stack and pull neutral camps to be able to get XP and farm without sapping it from the carry, and handle the pulled waves so that they don't clear the neutrals too quickly and then mess up the lane equilibrium.

Furthermore, the carry has to expect and know how to deal with farming in this situation without any friendly creeps. If you pull a wave with a carry that's never seen this before, he's likely to get confused and die.

Furtherfurthermore, you need to make sure the solo offlane player is actually playing a hero that is viable for the role i.e. capable of securing some levels and farm alone against two or three heroes in his lane without feeding, and the list for that is relatively small compared to other roles.

It's all a level of knowledge and coordination that cannot be automatically assumed in pub play until you get to a certain level of experience/gameplay. If you just play a tri-lane the same way you would normally play a dual lane, except with two supports instead of one, all you're likely to end up with is three underlevelled heroes in one lane and one guy in the offlane that's either going to have to play too safely to get any farm and experience or die a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I think it's a simple matter of lack of coordination.

The Pro Level DotA 2 teams practice together on a daily basis, they know their teammates, how they play, who can handle what, etc and it is a lot easier to coordinate a maneuver such as the Tri-Lane when you're confident in the rest of your team.

A Tri-Lane usually requires a pretty specific set of Heroes to be able to pull it off, and personally I don't usually see enough communication during picks for a PUB team to set something like that up. Half the games I play I consider myself lucky if we have a decent mid Hero...

There's a lot of details and play styles required to pull off an effective Tri-Lane and being matched with random players for a PUB match leaves too much to chance, so it's usually safer and easier to just go your standard 2-1-2 or 1-1-2-Jungle since that's what most people are familiar with and comfortable with.

Though I will say that a PUB team that could pull off a Tri-Lane would probably do some serious damage in Matchmaking. Good luck!

Comment: "I consider myself lucky if we have a decent mid Hero" let alone a support hero..

Comment: @turbo Fortunately I usually play support so I've got that covered. My problems are usually 4 Carries + Myself, 4 Melee + Myself, or no Mid

Comment: I almost always play support just because there are so few players at my level who can or will play support. AA, Jakiro, and Warlock all do well as support even if the other players aren't that good.